# Why crontab doesn't want to execute the job as root?

Tags: permissions, root, cron

I'am using the Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) version and i get a problem with my crontab (it was working before 13.10)

Here is the command line

```
/usr/lib/cgi-bin/awstats.pl -config=www.skrik.fr -update >/dev/null
```

If i run it as root in my terminal i get no error everything is working smoothly

But if i add it with *sudo crontab -e* i get

```
0 * * * * root /usr/lib/cgi-bin/awstats.pl -config=www.skrik.fr -update >/dev/null
```

> Error while processing /etc/awstats/awstats.cloud.skrik.fr.conf 
>   Create/Update database for config
>   "/etc/awstats/awstats.cloud.skrik.fr.conf" by AWStats version 7.2
>   (build 1.992)  From data in log file
>   "/var/log/apache2/cloud/access.log"...  Error: Couldn't open server
>   log file "/var/log/apache2/cloud/access.log" : Permission denied

I get the exact same problem when i add it to /etc/crontab

Why cron job doesn't want to work as root ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Danatela I'm not 100% sure if it's a bug. I'm not sure what the problem is, but the inconsistencies suggest that something else is wrong, IMO.

Comment: Hum the problem seems to be the new logrotate of apache. I will test new permission and come back to you. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/awstats/+bug/1252467

Comment: please put the solution in an answer below, we want to sepperate the question form the answer. Or it will be confusing for future visitors.

Comment: @Lezin I'm glad you found the answer! However, please move it to the answer section below, and then accept it when you can with the tick (I think you have to wait 24 hours). It's totally okay to answer your own questions! Cheers, and welcome to AskUbuntu!

Comment: Exactly I will wait tomorrow cause I can't at this time. Thanks all

Comment: You will have to wait until tomorrow to _accept_ your answer but you can post it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Here is the problem :

There is a awstats jobs setup on /etc/cron.d which is run with www-data.
This one is causing the problem cause www-data doesn't have access to /var/log/apache2

First you need to :

```
chmod o+rx /var/log/apache2
```

Next you need to change on */etc/logrotate.d/apache2*

```
create 640 root adm
```

Into:

```
create 644 root adm
```

restart the service.

My /etc/crontab was working fine. But i prefer to run the script with a non root accound.

Comment: Just curious to know why +x is needed here? I thought it was only about read access. Is there another meaning behind 'execute'